# How to reduce frame rate of an opencv image imported from ros

Tags: opencv, frame, rate, ros

I am new to both Opencv and ROS. I have the following code:

```
void visual_image_cb(const sensor_msg::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
    ctr++;
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try
    {
        cv_ptr=cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);
    }
    catch (cv_bridge:Exception& e)
    {
        ROS_ERROr("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
        return;
    }
...
```

How can I reduce the frame rate of `cv_ptr`? I tried using `cvQueryFrame` but that approach fails.

Is it possible to use `CvCapture` with `IplImage` (i.e. if i use `IplImage ipl_img= cv_ptr->image` and try to reduce the frame rate afterwards)?

Answer (score 1):

The callback you're using simply receives a message over ROS whenever a publisher publishes a message, so there is no way to actually reduce the frame rate from this point of view. You could choose to drop every number of frames, but this probably isn't what you're looking for, since you'll then just lose the data. If this **is** what you're looking for, just add some kind of counter to the function and only grab the image if the counter is equal to some value.

The solution would be to reduce the frame rate in the publisher. It's hard to give instructions for doing this without knowing what's publishing..but usually this is either some camera driver (ie OpenNI or Freenect) in which case you should go with the dropping frames approach from above. If the messages are being published from a ROS bag file, just add -r 0.5 to the end of the rosbag command to reduce the publish rate to half what it was recorded at.

-Tim